# Prevent toFixed from rounding off very small decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I have very small value, 0.09986684420772304, and I want to show it upto three decimals. toFixed rounds it off.

```
(0.09986684420772304).toFixed(3) ==> 0.100
```

I even tried

```
(Math.round(0.09986684420772304 * 100)/100).toFixed(3) => 0.100
```

What I need is

```
(0.09986684420772304).toFixed(3) ==> 0.0998
```

Please someone suggest me a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(0.09986684420772304).toPrecision(3)`

or `Math.floor(0.09986684420772304 * 10000) / 10000`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision

Comment: This still rounds the number to 0.999 which is not what the question asks for.